# Why does Spring call an aditional filter chain as well as an original filter chain?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

In my logs I found out that Spring is calling two separate filter chains while authorizing my request. So my question is, why does Spring call an **additional** filter chain as well as an **original** filter chain. Because this behaviour leads to my application authenticating a user twice while processing the request. Especially it is calling my AuthenticationFilter one time again unnecessarily.

Here you can see the log:

```
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/account/@me'; against '/api/account/**'
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/account/@me at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/account/@me at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/account/@me at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/account/@me at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'TokenAuthenticationFilter'
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] d.t.o.a.a.TokenAuthenticationFilter      : Request is to process authentication
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.authentication.ApplicationAuthenticationProvider
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.authentication.BearerAuthenticationProvider
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] d.t.o.a.a.TokenAuthenticationFilter      : Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.authentication.TokenAuthenticationToken@aeed7374: Principal: dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.authentication.OAuth2Principal@46a2793d; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: SCOPE_account.email, BEARER_ACCOUNT_1, SCOPE_account.basic, BEARER_ACCESS
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/account/@me at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/account/@me at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/account/@me at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.authentication.TokenAuthenticationToken@aeed7374: Principal: dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.authentication.OAuth2Principal@46a2793d; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: SCOPE_account.email, BEARER_ACCOUNT_1, SCOPE_account.basic, BEARER_ACCESS'
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/account/@me at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@5f8a02cf
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/account/@me at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/account/@me at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/api/account/@me' matched by universal pattern '/**'
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/account/@me; Attributes: [hasAnyAuthority('READ_ALL','BEARER_ACCESS')]
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.authentication.TokenAuthenticationToken@aeed7374: Principal: dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.authentication.OAuth2Principal@46a2793d; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: SCOPE_account.email, BEARER_ACCOUNT_1, SCOPE_account.basic, BEARER_ACCESS
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.h.RoleHierarchyImpl              : getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [SCOPE_account.email, BEARER_ACCOUNT_1, SCOPE_account.basic, BEARER_ACCESS] one can reach [SCOPE_account.email, BEARER_ACCOUNT_1, SCOPE_account.basic, BEARER_ACCESS] in zero or more steps.
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@2830c7a3, returned: 1
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
<< Additional Filter Chain Ends >> 27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/account/@me reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] d.t.o.a.a.TokenAuthenticationFilter      : Request is to process authentication
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.authentication.ApplicationAuthenticationProvider
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.authentication.BearerAuthenticationProvider
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] d.t.o.a.a.TokenAuthenticationFilter      : Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.authentication.TokenAuthenticationToken@c97cfb62: Principal: dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.authentication.OAuth2Principal@571022e9; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: SCOPE_account.email, BEARER_ACCOUNT_1, SCOPE_account.basic, BEARER_ACCESS
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.entities.json.AccountDTO dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.controllers.ApiController.getBearedAccount(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest); target is of class [dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.controllers.ApiController]; Attributes: [[authorize: 'hasAuthority('BEARER_ACCESS')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.authentication.TokenAuthenticationToken@c97cfb62: Principal: dev.teamnight.oauth2.authserver.authentication.OAuth2Principal@571022e9; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: SCOPE_account.email, BEARER_ACCOUNT_1, SCOPE_account.basic, BEARER_ACCESS
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.h.RoleHierarchyImpl              : getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [SCOPE_account.email, BEARER_ACCOUNT_1, SCOPE_account.basic, BEARER_ACCESS] one can reach [SCOPE_account.email, BEARER_ACCOUNT_1, SCOPE_account.basic, BEARER_ACCESS] in zero or more steps.
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@35948508, returned: 1
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@37c5e3bd
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
27-01-2021 DEBUG 10784 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

This is my WebSecurity Configuration:

```
        @Bean
        @Qualifier("accountApiAuthenticationFilter")
        public TokenAuthenticationFilter accountApiAuthenticationFilter(TokenAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler,
                TokenAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler) throws Exception {
            TokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
            filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
            filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
            filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
            filter.setAllowedTokenTypes(TokenType.APPLICATION, TokenType.BEARER);
            return filter;
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/api/account/**")
                .addFilterBefore(accountApiAuthenticationFilter(null, null), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("**").hasAnyAuthority("READ_ALL", "BEARER_ACCESS")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(this.appProvider)
                .authenticationProvider(this.bearerProvider)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new TokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .cors().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout().disable();
        }
```

Comment: Because you added the `TokenAuthenticationFilter` as a `Filter`. Any registered filter in the context will, by default, be added to the regular filter chain. You are adding it again to the security chain. You should add a `FilterRegistrationBean` which disables the registration for this filter for the regular filter chain.

Comment: @M. Deinum how do I do this because I have multiple configurations with two separate TokenAuthenticationFilter?

Comment: Add one for each of them.

Comment: @M.Deinum it actually works now, you can post it as answer, if you want, so I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot will, by default, register all `javax.servlet.Filter` instances in the regular `FilterChain`. You can influence this by adding a `FilterRegistrationBean` (from Spring Boot) to disable this registration.